# Exporting system.profile from MongoDB doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do export:

```
ilya@server ~]$ mongoexport --host localhost --port 27000  --collection system.users --db mydb --out profile.json                
connected to: localhost:27000
exported 1 records
```

Works ok with `system.users`

But doesn't work with `system.profile`:

```
[ilya@server ~]$ mongoexport --host localhost --port 27000  --collection system.profile --db mydb --out profile.json
connected to: localhost:27000
exported 0 records
```

Collection is not empty:

```
[ilya@server ~]$ mongo localhost:27000/mydb
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: localhost:27000/mydb
mongos> db.system.profile.count();
1044
```

I need these rows to export and work with them somewhere, for example as with normal collection(not capped as `system.profile`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [database-profiling-and-sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#database-profiling-and-sharding):

> You cannot enable profiling on a mongos instance. To enable profiling
>   in a shard cluster, you must enable profiling for each mongod instance
>   in the cluster.

Also see [mongoexport only exports one shard's worth of data](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3086) (although this bug is fixed since 1.9.1 and you use a much later version)

So try to `mongoexport` directly from the **mongod** instance that holds the `system.profile` collection you want.

**`**UPDATE**`**

A **second approach** is to not use mongoexport but to take the collection directly from the mongo shell (since you are able to see the collection from inside the mongo shell).

To do that first write the following script and save it to `print-profile.js`

```
c = db.system.profile.find();
while(c.hasNext()) {
  printjson(c.next());
}
```

then execute the following line from the bash shell:

```
mongo localhost:27000/mydb print-profile.js  > profile.json
```

Wait a little and in `profile.json` you will have the data you need.

Comment: Profiled data already collected, yeah i know, but thanks!I'll try to do so.

Comment: I have added a second approach to your problem, see if that helps you.

Comment: I confirm that using of mongoexport with system.profile collection works directly on mongod's.

Comment: @ilalopoulos, regarding the system.profile i have searched about it in side the mongodb directory but i haven't found it. is there any specific location for it, or is there any command that create this file in the directory of the mongodb ?

Comment: The second approach doesn't seem to produce valid JSON though.

Comment: @shams - it's not a file, but rather a collection in your db.

Comment: `mongoexport` option seems not to work on 3.2. It says: "error validating settings: collection name 'system.profile' is not allowed to begin with 'system.'" Does any body have a clue why it is not working?