# How to do export from `system.profile` collection

Tags: mongodb

We are trying profile performance and we have enabled profiling via:

```
> db.setProfilingLevel(0)
```

How we can export the data in `system.profile` collection?
After issuing:

```
$ mongoexport --db test --collection system.profile --out export.json
```

I'm getting:

```
2016-06-15T10:26:09.723+0200    error validating settings: collection name 'system.profile' is not allowed to begin with 'system.'
2016-06-15T10:26:09.723+0200    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

Is it anyhow possible? I'm sure I'm going against `master` and `mongod` instance and that the collection exists and contains data.

I found the following issue (for version 2.6), but it is obviously not working in 3.2.1, hence I'm asking again:
[Exporting system.profile from MongoDB doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881137/exporting-system-profile-from-mongodb-doesnt-work/17883223#comment62792550_17883223).

Does that changed within versions? Documentation says nothing about such limitation neither about any official workaround.

Comment: Did you tried `mongodump --db test --collection system.profile --out /home/youruser/Desktop/`? You can set your system path for `--out` param.

Comment: Yes it works, but our goal was to have JSON in the end. I have already find the way how to do it. Check my answer.

Comment: Yes but you did not mentioned your workaround. You should have to specify it while asking question.

Comment: @Vishwas I don't understand, which workaround? Do you mean that I wanted to have a JSON in the end? Workaround is mentioned in answer, simply it is not possible to have a strict JSON. You have to write a bunch of scripts. In my case it is one bash script. I've also mentioned that to get JSON you can use `bsondump`. Btw. sorry for not mentioning that I want to have JSON right from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profiled data is stored in system database and there is no chance to use mongoexport for that.

Create a javaScript file with content and save as ex.js

```
profileData = db.system.profile.find();
while(profileData.hasNext()) {
  printjson(profileData.next());
}
```

then run your mongo with:

> mongo hostName/databaseName ex.js > data.json

Comment: I'm accepting your question, while it is one of possible solutions and it works. But refer to my answer. I answered my own question to provide a complete list of options.

Comment: Btw. your script is not producing correct JSON document. So I've rephrased your solution to export correct JSON document as an Array. Next issue with such solution is that I've experienced troubles when trying to reimport it via `mongoimport`, but I still have to check that. Maybe in a next question.

Comment: @Teliatko - thanks for feedback - could you point what was improved in your version?

Answer (score 1):

As I have find out there are various solutions to the problem. I'm summarising all of them here to provide others a possibility for decision. And btw. behaviour of `mongoexport` is a bug in 3.2.

Which way to use is dependent from what kind of output do you want to have in the end. I mean if correct JSON document (strict) or "Mongo Shell JSON" or BSON. For details between JSONs in Mongo language "extended JSON" please refer to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

By "Mongo Shell JSON" I mean that the documents are written in the file but the whole file does not correspond to strict JSON and it is usually produced/consumed by Mongo tools like import, export.

**First**

To output BSON and afterwards "Mongo Shell JSON"
Easiest way, as already Vishwas mentioned is to use `mongodump`:

```
$ mongodump --host localhost:27017 --db test --collection system.profile
```

Optionally you can use `--out [path]` CLI parameter to redirect the output of the dump. Afterwards you will get in `{your out}/dump/test` subfolder an dump in BSON format, like `system.profile.bson`. Just to mention `dump` subfolder is organised as `{db}\{collection}.bson`.

To get an "Mongo Shell JSON" you can use `bsondump` utility as:

```
$ cd dump/test 
$ bsondump system.profile.bson > system.profile.json
```

There is no way to say `bsondump` to output data in strict JSON. Produced JSON file in "Mongo Shell JSON" and documents are just printed one after another. I mean not as JSON array. No make it strict JSON, you have to write yourself script to convert "Mongo Shell JSON" notation to strict JSON notation and even separate records with `,` and wrap them to `[` and `]`.

**Second**

Another approach is one mentioned by profesor79, but a bit modified to print directly to JSON array. It prints to "Mongo Shell JSON" directly.

```
use test;
c = db.system.profile.find().sort({ ts: 1 });
separator = '';

print("[");
while(c.hasNext()) {
  print(separator);
  printjson(c.next());
  separator = ',';
}
print("]");
```

I write it here just for convenience. If you do not need an array use snippet from profesor79 answer. Still you have to write an script to convert to strict JSON.

AFAIK there is no way how to get directly strict JSON. Good news are that `mongoimport` accepts "Mongo Shell JSON" even when the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) says:

> To preserve type information, mongoexport and mongoimport uses the strict mode representation for certain types.

**Explanation: Our goal was to have an strict JSON which is by us motivated with possibility to process the data elsewhere. Currently we are exporting "Mongo Shell JSON" and then converting it via bash script.**